# Определить другие ключи массива из возможных

Tags: php, массивы

Допустим, есть ключи массива:

```php
$cells = array(
    'A' => 'title',
    'B' => 'keywords',
    'C' => 'description',
    'D' => 'alias',
    'E' => 'artikul',
    'F' => 'content',
    'G' => 'price',
);
```

При загрузке Excel файла я могу получить и другие ключи, например, после `'G'` будут идти следующие буквы по алфавиту, то есть такой документ Excel не подходит, так как он заполнен неправильно.

Как мне проверить на соответствие ключей?
То есть в массиве должны присутствовать только ключи, показанные выше, и больше никаких других.  Если таковые найдутся, завершить выполнение.

Comment: собрать что нибудь из array_keys(), сортировки массива и потом implode получите строку из ключей типа 'A,B,C,...' ее можно сравнить с эталонной строкой.

Comment: @Mike Было бы отлично, если бы Вы показали вариант. Будет ответом на мой вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Проверка, что отсутствуют лишние ключи

```
$valid = ['A','B','C','D'];
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
foreach($keys as $key){
    if(!in_array(mb_strtoupper($key), $valid){
        die("Invalid key $key");
    }
}
```

Проверка, что ключи массива полностью совпадают с эталоном. Т.е. в массиве есть все необходимые ключи и нет никаких других. (То, о чем писал Mike) Предполагается, что ключи всегда состоят из одного символа.

```
$valid = 'ABCDE';
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
sort($keys);
$check = mb_strtoupper(implode($keys));
if($check !== $valid){
    die("Wrong keys");
}
```

Проверка, что ключи массива точно совпадают с шаблоном.

```
$valid = ['A','BR','C','1','foo'];
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
if(count($valid) !== count($keys)){
    die("Wrong keys");
}
foreach($keys as $key){
    if(!in_array($key, $valid){
        die("Invalid key $key");
    }
}
```

Comment: Второй вариант выдаст ошибку если в проверяемом массиве не будет всех нужных ключей или будут лишние, первый вариант только если будут лишние ключи. А еще для второго варианта все ок будет при `['ABC' => 1, 'DE' => 2]`.

Comment: @Visman я же вроде так и написал, что `Т.е. в массиве есть все необходимые ключи и нет никаких других.`. Первый вариант решает задачу как она поставлена, второй уже больше додумывание за автора. Вариант с ключем `ABC` добавлю, но по условию такого возникнуть не должно, если исключить варианты преднамерянного вредительства\